# There is no "Convert to Maven" Option when I do Right Click

Tags: eclipse, maven, bitbucket

I have a project which is divided into 3 sub project each for special purpose:

I put this project in bitbucket and then I imported it into eclipse but after importing the project,  when I right click, I cannot see the "Configure -> Convert to Maven" option. But when I click on the  folder (called omid) containing sub projects, I can find it. But I need to convert each sub project separately into maven since one of them is a webapp project, and the other are simple java projects. For more visualization look at the screenshots below:

[image]

But in the following image you can see what happens when I click on each sub project (there is no configure -> convert to maven):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you imported just the root module into Eclipse and you need to also explicitly import the sub modules as their own Maven projects. Go to File -> Import and choose the "Existing Maven Projects" option. Once this is selected you should be able to choose any project that contains a pom.xml file. You have two options from here. You could import both your root module (which is already imported) and all sub modules as Maven projects, or you can just import all sub modules.

Comment: Thanks a lot you have no idea what I went through to solve this problem :)